# Can I have a circular redirect in Grails?

Tags: grails, redirect, groovy

I'm trying to redirect circularly in Grails (no infinite redirect loop) and keep getting this error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException:
>   Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. The
>   response has already been committed
>   either by another redirect or by
>   directly writing to the response.

I am trying to do something like this where I redirect to another action on the controller then redirect back.  Wondering why Grails is not allowing this.

```
//initial action and final redirect location
def showStuff = {
        if (flash.neatStuff){
             return render("found neat stuff")
        } else if (params.email) {
            return redirect(action:'getNeatStuff',params:[email:params.email, emailOnly:true])
        }
        return render("Unable to find stuff, use param")
    }

def getNeatStuff = {
        flash.neatStuff = new Date()
        if (params.emailOnly){
              redirect(action:'showStuff')
        }
        redirect(action:'someOtherPlace')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a total brain fart.  I corrected the code below in case anyone runs into this same error.  I was racking my brain looking at other things, but I just wasn't returning the redirect on the action.

```
def getNeatStuff = {
        flash.neatStuff = new Date()
        if (params.emailOnly){
              return redirect(action:'showStuff')
        }
        redirect(action:'someOtherPlace')
}
```